# Run pyspark dataframe in dataproc from docker container

Tags: docker, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, dataproc

1- I have created a dataproc cluster with docker as initialization-action

```
gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/docker/docker.sh
```

According to: https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/docker
docker should be configured in the master as well as in worker nodes

2- I have SSH in the master, installed docker-compose and cloned my app there. My app is a flask (python) server, which on API request, processes some data and sends back a response.

**As my logic is inside docker containers, I want to call the dataproc master from inside my container.**
I have installed pyspark in my container but I am not sure how I can run pyspark code from my docker containers that can be executed by dataproc master + workers on the host?